# Watson conversation: Detecting entities within a sentence having some intent for untrained cases

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

Im looking to train my bot to basically extract the weight from a type of sentence and tag the intent as "#enterBMI".
I have also created an entity "@weight". I will show below in images what i have trained the bot with - [image: enterBmiTraining]
[image: weightTraining]

The problem i am facing is that weight is detected only for exactly the same weights that i have given training for. So 100 kg will be detected and 101 kg/100 kgs will not be detected.
[image: TheProblem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use @sys-number entity instead of a dedicated @weight
[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the clarity. The issue will come if someone enters 'please enter my bmi reading, my height is 190 cm and weight is 44 kg' then i will get 2 numbers by parsing the entity list however i will not be able to pinpoint which is weight and which is height very easily. Can any other watson service be used to do the above or will Watson Conversation be evolved in the future?  Also can you please tell me which watson services/technologies have been used in 'IBM Watson for Oncology'. Is there any good reference for the same... @Dudi

Comment: @RnjaiLamba Your problem is a known issue. There are a few methods to tackle it. 1) Try to ask close questions such as: "What is your weight" and not "Can you tell me your measurements". B. In your specific case you can disambiguate based on the values. C. You can use external services to analyze your sentence and extract the relevant entities. I would consider two approaches, NLP rule based or develop a model in Watson Knowledge Studio and hand over the sentence to it.

Comment: Perfect i will give Watson Knowledge Studio a shot. Does 'IBM Watson for Oncology' use something like this? I am very intrigued by the capabilities of 'IBM Watson for Oncology'. Thanks